# password_verify fails in an if statement

Tags: php, sql

EDIT: I guess the stars just fell out of alignment, because after reloading the page and trying to use it again it works.

---

I'm creating a simple administration system with user accounts. I'm having a hard time with the login bit, because for some reason `password_verify` fails if it's in an if statement. It might be related to my method of getting the passwords out of the database, but I'm not sure.

here's what doesn't work

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` = '" . $db->real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "';");

if (!$query or $query == NULL)
{
    echo $db->error . "<br>";
    exit("EXIT: database error");
}

while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $row['password']))
    {   
        $db->close();
        header("LOCATION: main.php");
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        header("LOCATION: index.php?error=Wrong password.");
        exit("wrong password<br>");
    }
}
```

if I were to replace the line `if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $row['password']))` with

```
$success = password_verify($_POST['password'], $row['password']);
if ($success)
// success
```

it works as expected. is there something wrong with me doing `($row = $query->fetch_assoc())`, or did I make a mistake somewhere else? I don't understand why it won't work in the IF statement. I'm sure I just did something stupid, but I cannot for the life of me find out what.

Would it be bad, or considered bad for me to use the latter method for password authentication?

Comment: your line `$success = password_v` is missing a close )

Comment: _Side note:_ In this line. `if (!$query or $query == NULL)`, the `or` part isn't needed. Just have `if (!$query)` is enough since it would cover `null` as well (it's falsy).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I thought about that, but I wasn't sure, and it's everywhere in the codebase (which is very old) so I didn't want to remove it just yet.

Comment: There's no difference between having `password_verify()` in an `if`-statement or storing the result in a variable and check that instead. If you get a difference, there must be something else wrong, like you passing the wrong password or similar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I seem to have fixed the problem somewhere in here:

```
if (!empty($_POST['password']))
{   
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $row['password']))
        {                   
            $db->close();
            header("LOCATION: main.php");
            exit("EXIT: Logged in successfully.");
        }
        else
        {               
            header("LOCATION: index.php?error=Wrong password.");
            exit("EXIT: Wrong password");
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think it was the actual code that was the problem, but my databases. I don't know if it has anything to do with it, but phpmyadmin is showing duplicates for all my rows. I'm still very new to using SQL (today) so I don't know if that's normal. Maybe I just needed to give it time to update the tables? Who knows.

Answer (score -2):

1. Make sure to sanitize your inputs, **never** simply use `$_POST['password']`, but use a [sanitize filter](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) instead.
2. For me your first block of code works just fine and your second one has mismatched parenthesis.

Comment: Parameterizing should be in used over sanitizing. The `mysqli` function would sanitize the input, but it has known flaws which is why the parameterizing is better.

Comment: ...and why would you sanitize `$_POST['password']` when it's never sent to the database or echoed? It's only passed to `password_verify()`, which is perfectly OK to do without any sanitation/escaping. It actually _shouldn't_ be sanitized/escaped since that would actually _change_ the password.

Comment: Don't post comments as answers. If you don't have enough rep to comment, work on that first. Answers are reserved for actual _solutions_. Commenting is a privilege and trying to bypass the rep restrictions like this is _not_ a good way to earn rep, rather the opposite.

Comment: @user3783243: No mysqli_real_escape_string() does not have flaws it just makes it possible to do REALLY STUPID things. OTOH parameter binding can break function calls by implicit casting and doesn't support variable lists.

Comment: @symcbean - _"No mysqli_real_escape_string() does not have flaws"_ - Yes, it does... sure it's in edge cases but they do exist:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string/12118602#12118602

Comment: @symcbean I guess I should have phrased the issue with the `escaping` differently (and called it escaping, not `mysqli`). Are you playing devil's advocate or do you really believe parameterizing is not a better approach?

Comment: @Magnus: like I said, it doesn't prevent you doing really stupid things. Would you really fall on your keyboard and implement a charset change bypassing the API, employing one of the three vulnerable character sets by accident?